# Prove that $\log_a\left(\frac{2ab}{a+b}\right)\log_b\left(\frac{2ab}{a+b}\right)\geq 1$

Tags: inequality, logarithms, a.m.-g.m.-inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

Prove that $$\log_a\left(\frac{2ab}{a+b}\right)\log_b\left(\frac{2ab}{a+b}\right)\geq 1$$ if a and b are between 0 and 1
I'm stuck.It should be solved using one of the four means or by getting an obvious statement. Not sure which one and how to solve it.

Comment: Is there some assumption concerning $a$ and $b$? Such as that they are greater that $1$, for instance?

Comment: i think it must be $$a>0,b>0$$ and $$a,b\neq 1$$

Comment: Just got info that they should be between 0 and 1, sorry for this.

Comment: you want to show
$$
[\ln(2ab)-\ln(a+b)]^2\geqslant \ln a\cdot\ln b
$$

Comment: So we need to assume 0<a,b<1?

Comment: For a,b>1 it seems to work

Comment: Maybe for 0<a,b<1 we can convert to an equivalent statement!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $0<a,b<1$ let's assume $c=\frac1a$ $d=\frac1b$

$$\log_a\left(\frac{2ab}{a+b}\right)\log_b\left(\frac{2ab}{a+b}\right)\geq 1 \iff$$

$$\frac{\log\left(\frac{2ab}{a+b}\right)\log\left(\frac{2ab}{a+b}\right)}{\log a \log b}\geq 1 \iff$$

$$\frac{\log\left(\frac{c+d}{2}\right)\log\left(\frac{c+d}{2}\right)}{\log c \log d}\geq 1 \iff$$

For AM-GM

$$\log \frac{c+d}{2}\geq \log \sqrt {cd} =\frac{\log c+\log d}{2} \geq \sqrt{\log c \log d}$$

Thus

$$\frac{\log\left(\frac{c+d}{2}\right)\log\left(\frac{c+d}{2}\right)}{\log c \log d}\geq \frac{\log c \log d}{\log c \log d}= 1 \quad \square$$

Comment: $\log(x)$ is an increasing function, how did you get that last inequality? Also, it's not clear if $\log{a}\cdot \log{b}$ is always positive or negative.

Comment: I was assuming a,b>1, isn't it?

Comment: Maybe it's a mistake in my book, nevertheless, a good answer.

Comment: I'm trying to verify if it's valid also for 0<a,b<1!

Comment: Wait ... you have from AM-GM $\frac{a+b}{2} \geq \frac{2ab}{a+b}$ and $\log{x}$ is increasing ... again, how did you obtain $\log{\frac{2ab}{a+b}} \geq \log{\frac{a+b}{2}}$?

Comment: @rtybase you are right, I chek again mu work. Thanks!

Comment: @user410918 Please unaccept the answer I need to revise!

Comment: @rtybase now I think that it's ok!

Answer (score 0):

By AM-GM and C-S we obtain:
$$\log_a\frac{2ab}{a+b}\log_b\frac{2ab}{a+b}\geq\log_a\frac{2ab}{2\sqrt{ab}}\log_b\frac{2ab}{2\sqrt{ab}}=\log_a\sqrt{ab}\log_b\sqrt{ab}=$$
$$=\frac{1}{4}\left(1+\log_ab\right)\left(1+\log_ba\right)\geq\frac{1}{4}\left(1+\sqrt{\log_ab\log_ba}\right)^2=1.$$